# Magento shows (two) wrong taxes in full tax summary but only in the BE and on emails and the totals are correct

Tags: tax, tax-class

When a order is placed our Magento shows two taxes in the full tax summary on the order confirmation email as well as in the backend. One of this tax is the correct German tax the other is some US tax which seems random to me and I don't know where it comes from. For example "US-All States-MemberOnlyTaxableGoodsRate (7.25%)", "US-All States-NotloggedinTaxableGoodsRate (8%)", "US-All States-GeneralTaxableGoodsRate (7.5%)" to name but a few - and I cannot even find these rates in [Sales] -> [Tax] -> [Manage Tax Rates]. I only have 0%, 7% and 19% rates set up there. Sometimes these US taxes also seem way off. For a 71.06 € product it just showed "US-All States-MemberOnlyTaxableGoodsRate (7.25%): 39,88 €". No idea how a 7.25% rate can be 39,88 € for this product.

The good thing is it just shows these rates in the full tax summary, if I fade it out the total tax is only the correct German tax (which also always is in the full tax summary next to the US tax). With that the grand total is also always correct. Still this is very confusing for customers.
Also worth to mention is that this only happens after the order is placed. So if you fade in the tax summary in the cart or the onepage checkout only the correct German tax is shown.

Of course all of our products have the same tax class and all our customers have German addresses.

Any clues where I could start looking?

Comment: Well you're not going to see information displayed for tax rates that don't exist...

Comment: If you are implying I should simply delete those rates believe me I have tried but as written they are not in the BE where I have set up the others. One should guess a text phrase like "MemberOnlyTaxableGoodsRate" cannot be built from nothing and this is why I grepped through all files of my installation (no results) and my whole DB where it only comes up in `sales_order_tax`, `tax_order_aggregated_created` and `tax_order_aggregated_updated` but not in `tax_calculation_rate_title` where I would have expected it. I don't know from where Magento gets these information and thus how to trace it...

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141330)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a table sales_order_tax that keeps Magento dummydata. Simply you should delete old data here. I can happen that your new order has the same id as the dummy Magento order and you see strange tax rule. I had the same issue with Polish VAT.

Comment: This worked. As `sales_order_tax` seemed to be for specific orders only I couldn't imagine that it has any influence on new orders. We only deleted the first entries there which didn't match our orders and really were a relic from the sample data and so far no strange names showed up in the detailed tax report. Thanks for the tip! (Our workaround before btw was simply to hide the detailed tax report in the order confirmation mail.)